# User redirected to a really bad URL after logging into Magento-based site with Safari on Mac OSX & iOS

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewrite

I really don't know what to call this. It seems only to happen on both Mac OSX and iOS with Safari. It doesn't seem to affect Chrome even though they are both Webkit-based.

I'm working on a B2B project where we are using Magento as the primary development framework. Linking to the site, the user must log on to do anything. I've been primarily developing on a Windows machine then pushing the code to a LEMP machine. I encounter no problems with any browser on Windows or Android.

On a Mac with Safari I link to the site. The page displays as expected. I enter my correct credentials and click on the login button. I receive a message that the server cannot be found. When I look at the address bar, I see this strangeness:

```
://://:///?SID=m4sc01d4rgptruhv3jf4efari4
```

Yes, *that* is the URL the system wants to redirect to.

I've also seen "localhost" on iOS. I don't have localhost anywhere in the (non-database) configuration that I can find in a global search of the source code.

I did some searching looking for anything related to that broken URL and all I found were some references to turning off the SID. I did that just to see what happens, and now I receive this URL:

```
://://:///
```

I've only seen this with Safari on Mac OSX or iOS.

Edit: Reloading / Relinking to the original site URL loads the site as if I were redirected there after log in.

Answer (score 2):

That's certainly not part of standard Magento system behavior.  Unfortunately, the phrase

> I'm working on a B2B project

leads me to the conclusion there's a lot of custom code in this project, which means you're unlikely to find a solution to your problem here.

Generally speaking, I'd start by adding some logging to `_redirect` in either your frontend of backend admin controller (depending on what "log in" means to you), and when you see a `://:...` string coming though, drop a `madeDebugBacktrace();exit;` in there and determine which file the redirect request is coming from.

A less technical approach would be to disable all the custom extensions, and then reenable them until the behavior reemerges.